# iOS: Prevent URL from being percent escaped automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, url

I'm fetching some JSON data using `URLSession.dataTask`. To filter the data, I'm using a parameter that limits by date. The API uses square brackets for this, e.g.

`https://foo.com/api/items.json?find[date]=...`.

However, upon creating a URL with the string and requesting data from it, the square brackets are automatically escaped:

`https://foo.com/api/items.json?find%5Bdate%5D=...`

With the brackets escaped, the API fails to recognize the request.

I've tried explicitly removing the percent encoding to create a new URL, i.e.

`let unsanitized = URL(string: url.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding)`

but the percent sanitization persists.

I've spent a lot of time searching for a solution but haven't had any success—any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the spec for URI: "A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6 [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal within square brackets ("[" and "]")." [rfc3986.](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Thus you can't use square brackets for your purpose without escaping them.  Your server's REST service is at fault for not handling the escaped characters in the query params.  (And I've had situations in recent past where I've had to ask my REST team to fix this sort of problem where they forgot to support escaped query parameter values).

Answer (score 3):

Try use `percentEncodedQueryItems` of URLComponents instead `queryItems`.
This is my codes in my app.

```
let fullUrl = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
guard var components = URLComponents(url: fullUrl, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else {
    fatalError("Unable to create URL components")
}
var params = self.parameters // <-- parameters = [String:String]
params["serviceKey"] = Const.OPEN_API_KEY // <-- percent encoded key
components.percentEncodedQueryItems = params.map { // <-- already percent encoded Query Items
    URLQueryItem(name: String($0), value: String($1))
}
guard let url = components.url else {
    fatalError("Could not get url")
}
```